# Merge [autolayout] into [ios-autolayout]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

These two tags are the same.  I think they should be merged.

- Note that the description of [autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout) is actually describing "iOS autolayout." [ios-autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-autolayout) describes the same.
- There's no other technology named "autolayout". (There's no google autolayout, sinclair autolayout, or whatever.)

Probably they should be merged or one should be deleted. I propose we keep [ios-autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-autolayout) as it is more clear when to use.

Comment: You might note that [tag:autolayout] has 5,744 questions and a tag wiki, whereas [tag:ios-autolayout] has 156 questions and no wiki. That might guide the process and make the decision an easier one. Also that the [autolayout] wiki explicitly notes that it's about the iOS/Mac autolayout, so ambiguity isn't an issue.

Comment: @PaulRoub: The tag-wiki is not the only relevant thing, how it's actually used counts too. [Looking for questions which might not fit that description](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bautolayout%5d%20-%5bios*%5d%20-%5bosx%5d%20-%5b*iphone*%5d%20-%5bcocoa%5d%20-%5bobjective-c%5d%20-%5bswift%5d%20is%3aq), they *do* exist.

Comment: Stumbled across [tag:cs193p], which should be merged (not synonymized) to ios, while [going though these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bautolayout%5d%20-%5bios*%5d%20-%5bosx*%5d%20-%5b*iphone*%5d%20-%5bipad*%5d%20-%5b*cocoa*%5d%20-%5bobjective-c%5d%20-%5binterface-builder%5d%20-%5bswift%5d%20-%5bnslayout*%5d%20-%5bxcode*%5d%20is%3aq).

Comment: Other questions needing separate handling: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31623167 http://stackoverflow.com/q/28478936 http://stackoverflow.com/q/20137552 http://stackoverflow.com/q/24077590 http://stackoverflow.com/q/29614739 http://stackoverflow.com/q/28525131 http://stackoverflow.com/q/10709485